# Obstacles to computing $\pi(n)$ in $O(n^{2/3-\epsilon})$ time

Tags: prime-numbers, computational-complexity, lower-bounds

**Edit:** Apologies, as mentioned in the comments I failed to notice the analytic algorithms that take $O(n^{1/2+\epsilon})$ time, so this question doesn’t make much sense.  It’s possible there is a sensible question restricting to sieve-like algorithms, but I don’t know how to make that precise.

The fastest algorithms for computing $\pi(n)$ (counting primes up to $n$) appear to require $\tilde{O}(n^{2/3})$ time (ignoring logarithmic factors).  For example, [Deleglise and Rivat](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1996-65-213/S0025-5718-96-00674-6/S0025-5718-96-00674-6.pdf) give an algorithm with complexity $O(n^{2/3}/\log^2 n)$, which is itself an improvement to several other algorithms with similar complexity.  The two-thirds power lower bound seems to be because one needs to sieve up through $n^{2/3}$ and explicitly handle primes in that range to deal with inclusion/exclusion interactions of smaller factors.

**Question:** Is it possible to get a rigorous $\Omega(n^{2/3-\epsilon})$ lower bound for some natural black box generalization of $\pi(n)$?

For example, can we replace $\mathbb{N}$ by some larger class of black box arithmetic semigroups (monoids with a norm and a set of primes) such that similar algorithms work for counting primes and there is a matching rigorous lower bound?

Comment: Some google-fu (with the name of Andrew Odlyzko which I happened to remember) lead to this MO post https://mathoverflow.net/questions/53278/prime-counting-any-fast-alternatives-to-the-lagarias-miller-odlyzko-combinator , which had the following link https://www.mail-archive.com/sage-devel@googlegroups.com/msg44646.html , from which it apears that already in the late 80's there were $O(n^{1/2 + \varepsilon})$ algorithms for the prime counting function. And indeed, it is literally mentioned on the first page of the Deleglise--Rivat paper, how did you miss it?

Comment: Apologies, I swapped in that link after reading in more detail about some of the prior algorithms, and incorrectly though it was $O(n^{2/3})$ still based on Wikipedia not mentioning the faster algorithms in the algorithm section of  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function.

Comment: Indeed, the paper I read in detail was the 1985 paper which predated by two years the analytic paper you mention by the same authors. :/

Comment: And one would expect the analytic methods to extend similarly to other arithmetic semigroups, so likely it’s $O(n^{1/2+\epsilon})$ for those as well.  So apologies for the noise.